# Find pair values MySQL Query between min and max in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table:

[image: Tables]

Can't run query, to display "Result" table, pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t2.id1,
    t2.col
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
    ON  t1.nr1 BETWEEN t2.MinNr1 AND t2.MaxNr1
    AND t1.nr2 BETWEEN t2.MinNr2 AND t2.MaxNr2
```

Answer (score 0):

Work only with:

INNER JOIN table2 t2

On t1.nr1 >= t2.MinNr1 And t1.<= t2.MaxNr1

And t1.nr2 >= t2.MinNr2 And t2.MinNr2 <= t2.MaxNr2